# Cyanogenmod unlocked phone requires network unlock code

Tags: cyanogenmod, sim-unlocking

I have a Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc that I installed Cyanogenmod (v. 9.1.0-anzu).
The phone is not locked to a specific network as a) the danish operator where I bought the phone does not do this and b) I recently changed operator without any hassle.

I now have two possible related problems.

1. A couple of times per day, the sim card needs unlocking. As in when I unlock the phone, it requests the PIN code. Not a major issue, but a nuisance.
2. After entering the PIN code, the phone requests the network unlock code, to which I press the "Cancel"-button.

I've been searching the googles, but most hits reply that I should restore ROM to stock, get the network unlock code and unlock the phone. But this seems a bit ridicules, as the phone isn't locked.

And now I'm here. Thanks!

Comment: I would try another ROM to be honest, I've never installed CM without having issues of some kind, on about 12 devices at this stage.

Comment: Well shucks. Any suggestions for other widely used ROMs that might or might not support my phone?